# Python: Accessing Modules in a Folder using import <module> instead of from <module> import *

Tags: python, python-import

I have a nested class that is similar to

```
/Foo
    __init__.py
    pitythefoo.py
    kungfoo.py
    /Bar
        __init__.py
        spam.py
        eggs.py
```

My `__init__.py` files currently have

`__all__ = ['pitythefoo', 'kungfoo']` for the `/Foo/__init__.py` file and

`__all__ = ['spam', 'eggs']` for the `/Foo/Bar/__init__.py` file,

so I can access spam and eggs using

```
from Foo.Bar import *
spam
eggs
```

However, I would like to access spam and eggs using

```
from Foo import Bar
Bar.spam
Bar.eggs
```

Is there some code that I can use in my `__init__.py` files to have this sort of import?

Comment: I suggest you have a read through e.g. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: @Bryce93: just import the names inside your `__init__.py`. If you want to use `__all__`, the answer is below. If you hate star-imports (as I do), import the names explicitly

Comment: Top tip: if `__all__` is the same as everything you'd get anyway, there's no need to include it. `Bar/__init__.py` should contain e.g. `import spam`, `Foo/__init__.py` should contain nothing.

Comment: Note also that, using section 6.4 as an example, if you `from sound import effects`, then access to `effects.echo`, etc., is *precisely what you get*.

Answer (score 0):

You could hack your way around it by modifying your `Foo/Bar/__init__.py`:

```
__all__ = ['spam', 'eggs']

from . import *
```

It works, but it definitely isn't elegant.

**EDIT**:
As [Andrea Corbellini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1913824/andrea-corbellini) pointed out in the comment above, you can avoid the star-import:

```
from . import spam
from . import eggs
```